# How to use react-transition-group CSSTransition to animate on page load?

Tags: reactjs, react-transition-group

I have a sandbox with two components that render an animated div. One has a button which uses the in prop to render the animated div and this works ok. The other component is meant to animate once on page load. But there is no animation, it just renders the div. How do i use CSSTransition to animate on page load?

https://codesandbox.io/s/csstransition-component-page-load-vs-button-k41xu?file=/index.js

any help appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

i fixed it by adding additional state to the auto component to set the in prop on css transition. apparenytly it needs to switch to work.

```
  let [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(()=>setShow(true), 1000);
  }, [])

  then

  <CSSTransition in={show}...
```